# Excel formula - index match address indirect rank.avg

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

Need help crafting formula.

I have data in SQL, exporting to excel. In excel have formula's to determine rank of parts based on values in a certain week in a range/array. The columns are weekly buckets, and each time I export, the weekly buckets change (no dates in the past). I would like the rank to remain fixed a specific date, but each export per week the specific column comes inward by 1 column.

I need an excel formula which finds the position of the specific value in the weekly bucket array. After this is determined, I need another formula to convert this column address (e.g. "AX") to be referenced by the rank.avg function.

I am guessing this is some combination of match, index, cell, indirect, & rank.avg. So far I have tried just the first part and cannot get cell("col",(index(match))) to return the letter values of the column it is in. It returns the # of the column instead.

Here is example

```
  A       B        C         D
1 Part    Rank(C)  11/28/17  12/04/17
2 Part A  1        $100      $100    
3 Part B  2        $50       $125    
4 Part C  3        $25       $200
```

Column B has the rank formula which is determining the rank of the parts (A,B,C) from column C. Column C is determining from hardcoding go to the value 11/28/17.

I am stuck at =CELL("address",INDEX(C1:D1,1,MATCH(43067,C1:D1,0))). This returns $C$1 when I just want $C or just C. Afterwards I intend to use this with indirect to be able to pass it through the rank function. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated where someone can fill the gap on the formula or come up with an easier way to do this.

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes get rid of ADDRESS and INDIRECT and just put the column in a COUNTIF formula.

ADDRESS and INDIRECT are volatile.  This is an non-Volatile and non-Array formula that does what you want in one step:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(C:D,2,MATCH(43067,$C$1:$D$1,0)):INDEX(C:D,1040000,MATCH(43067,$C$1:$D$1,0)),">" & INDEX(C:D,ROW(),MATCH(43067,$C$1:$D$1,0))) + 1
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you getting 1 for the rank because the date is being included in the COUNTIF? I'd expect you'd want to exclude row 1 but add 1 to the COUNTIF result to get the correct rank

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the assist here. I have modified it successfully to use it in my file! The array is about 53 columns vs 120 rows. I am not sure I fully understand the formula, will have to step through it when I am less busy. But, you are correct it is in one-step (quick) and the file size hasn't ballooned out of control. You appear to have side-stepped the rank formula entirely and it works. There is some minor weird stuff (like it jumps from rank 10 to rank 12 and skips rank 11) but appears to be accurate. I don't think I would have come up with this at all. Great trick.

Comment: @barryhoudini, yes you are correct.  I will fix. I was being lazy.

Comment: @barryhoudini you may be correct, and I actually got rank 0 on my top result (expected 1), so I just did +1 to the end of the formula. You are probably correct with the date getting added, but I am concerning about big $$ and the date is just too small to affect the ranking I am doing in this application.

Comment: @Nicho247 fixed the formula to exclude the data in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the column letter you could get fancy with `Address` and `Substitute`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(43067, C1:D1,0)+2,4), "1", "")
```

Address takes in a column and row and spits out a cell. So we just always reference row 1 and whatever column is returned from address (`+2` since we are starting at `C` in Match). Then we substitute out the `1` from the returned cell address with nothing to be left with the column letter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your formula returns cell reference in form of `C1` you can wrap it with:

```
=CHAR(64+COLUMN(C1))
```

Just change `C1` with your formula.